# Non-jumping parallax with IE11 - but how?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11, parallax

On my website, I experience - and a lot of others do on theirs - a kind of jumping/lagging effect with Internet Explorer 11 (on a Windows 8.1 machine) when creating a parallax. On Firefox for example it is working absolutely fine.

According to my research, this is a common problem with IE11 that has no solution, but I have found a website that somehow fixed the issue (or made a Workaround?!?) :
http://focuslabllc.com/journal

But my website has the same issue as this one:
http://negativespacealphabet.com/
What are they doing differently to get it work? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Maybe this helps you? https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Comment: Example: http://pixeljuice.ru/en (scroll)

Comment: Read the source; they are using [jQuery Waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints) with [ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).

Comment: There is no parallax effect on the first site, just some elements that have fixed positioning. The second site could be mimicked using CSS clip, something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgGlu

Comment: ^ to clarify I interpret 'parallax' as moving layers to give the appearance of distance rather than a combination of scrollable/static content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solution I have seen to this issue is to use transition on whatever properties you are using to create the parallax.

Example, you use `transform:translateY` to create a parralax effect, then add:

```
transition:transform 10ms linear
```

This forces the parralax to animate smoothly.
Downside, its not fully backward compatible with older browsers

Comment: Thanks a lot Drew!